# credentials in a json file not publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a credentials.json file which I am using to read from a google spreadsheet. Whenever I publish my project and then install it I get the following error on the running console

```
10:22:47 Gateway     Ready
Could not find file 'C:.........\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\CNGZMBDO.AW5\5Q46RK94.H5Q\disc..tion_b9a283b9ed494543_0001.0000_08ee2c8ed3d4507d\credentials.json'.
```

how can I fix this? The "copy to output directory" property is set to "Copy Always"

I am using c# and visual studio 2017

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: @Tarik the code is here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: The json file is located in the same location as the exe file? Because, since you do not specify an absolute path, a relative path will be used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you publish it via ClickOnce. If so, did you try to include the file into `Application Files...`, set its Publish Status to Data File?

[image]

And then access it like

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\File\b.jpg");
```